# Doesn't return collection from entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5

I'm a junior in EntityFramework and I have such a problem. I create Entity User:

```
public class User:IdStatus

    {
        public string Info { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public int  Rating { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PlayedQuestion> PlayedQustions { get; set; }
    }
```

and entity PlayedQuestion:

```
public class PlayedQuestion:IdStatus
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public bool IsSolve { get; set; }
}
```

When I add new played question to user in my app, this question is saved normally in my data base, but when I get user and try to enumerate its PLAYEDQUESTIONS collection, the error appears: Null reference exception because PlayedQuestions collection is null. Please, 
explore me, why this questions doesn't get from database with user, Thanks

Comment: When you write your LINQ query, did you invoke the `include` method? Something like `db.Users.Include(a => a.PlayedQuestions)`. You need to call the `include` method so that the query will eagerly load your `PlayedQuestion` entity assoicated with your `User` entity

Comment: it alttle unclear I believe you defined USER and Question as pk in your entity PlayedQuestion: have you trid to get just the Question from PlayedQuestion it might be your LINQ problem

Comment: If you do not use eager loading (e.g. via .include) you need to mak the navigation properties **virtual**, so that EF can perform lazy load, e.g.:
`public virtual ICollection<PlayedQuestion> PlayedQustions { get; set; }`

Comment: Is this code-first, or did you use the visual designer to create the mapping?

Comment: Thanks for answers - the virtual ICollection<PlayedQuestion> really worked. But I don't understand now why)